# Prime Degree Field Extension Separable

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $p$ be a prime and $L$ is a prime degree field extension of $K$, therefore $[K: L]=p$. Why is then $L$ ***separable*** over $K$?

Comment: Without some further hypothesis, it's not necessarily true that $L$ is separable over $K$.

Comment: As it is given, that's false.

Comment: Ah ok I see it. For example if $char(K)=p$ and $L=K(a)$(neccessary) with arbitrary minimal polynomial of the schape $p_a= X^p -a^p$ provides a conterexample?

Comment: Yours will work, but $K$ will have to be an infinite field of characteristic $p$. As an example, if $K=\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, then $L=K(t^{1/p})$ is not separable, but has degree $p$ over $K$. In this case the minimal polynomials is $p_t=X^p-t$.

Comment: @C.W.: Why is here $X^p-t$ irreducible? I can here only conclude that it is divided by the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @KarlPeter In $L$ this polynomial factors as $(X-t^{1/p})^p$, and so any polynomial that divides it will have the form $(X-t^{1/p})^k$ for some $0\leq k\leq p$. The Binomial Theorem then tells us that this is not a polynomial in $K[X]$ for any $0<k<p$, so it can't factor in $K[X]$.

Answer (score 2):

From Serge Lang, Algebra, 2002, p.254, exercise 14:

> Let $\text{char}\; K = p.$ Let $L$ be a finite extension of $K$, and suppose $[L : K]$ prime to
> $p$. Show that $L$ is separable over $K$.

Maybe you meant this? In which case, it follows from the fact that the minimal polynomial of any purely inseparable element $\alpha\in L$ over $K$ has degree $p^{\mu}$ for some integer $\mu$, and hence $p^{\mu}\mid [L:F]$, which can only be the case when $\mu=0$ i.e. $L$ is separable over $K$.

Comment: Dear Divide1918: Thank you for pointing the exercise above out. I was looking for it!